# Existence of partial of derivative implies existence of partial of partial

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, frechet-derivative

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be Frechet differentiable. Show carefully that if $f'$ has directional derivative $D_u f'(a)$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $u\neq 0$, then for every $v\neq 0$ ,the directional derivative $D_uD_v f(a)$ exists and equals $D_uf'(a) (v)$

Please do not post a solution to this problem, you only have to say why I'm right or wrong to get your points

The "show carefully" has thrown me because I think I have two just too easy to believe ways of proving the statement. I can't convince myself that they're right.

Way 1:

$$D_u f'(a) v=D_u[f'(a)v]=D_u[D_vf(a)]=D_uD_vf(a)$$

I doubt I can use associativity in this way, thats probably wrong. But then I have a slightly more roundabout way of doing the same thing,

Way 2:

$$D_u f'(a)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f'(a+tu)-f'(a)}{t}
\\ \iff t D_uf'(a)+o(t)=f'(a+tu)-f'(a)\\\ f'(a+tu)=f'(a)+tD_uf'(a)+o(t)$$
Apply the operator to $v$,
$$ f'(a+tu)v=f'(a)v+t[D_uf'(a)]v+o(t)$$
Use $D_vf(x)=f'(x)v$ then $$D_v f(a+tu)=D_vf(a)+t D_uf'(a)v+o(t)
$$
which is the defintion of the partial derivative so done?

Comment: way 1 looks right to me, i guess i'm missing something too. If $D_u D_v f$ is not $D_u ( D_v f)$ then I have no idea what it actually is. Maybe by "show carefully" they want you to check that $a\mapsto f'(a)(v)$ is also directionally differentiable in direction $u$? which is not the same per se as the directional differentiability of $f'$. And this is what way 2 checks? I guess how "careful" you need to be would depend on the precise list of things you can take for granted

Comment: @CalvinKhor That is reassuring, thanks